# Understanding setSelect()->join Need to join two custom collections

Tags: collection, select, join

I am confused understanding the correct usage of `$collection->getSelect()->join(...` to bring two custom model resources together.  I tried following other examples using the getSelect method.  I also attempted to join the tables in the collection class _afterLoad() method.  I'm stuck with errors like:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'machinemanager_machine_metertype.meter_type_id' in 'on clause', query was: SELECT `main_table`.*, `table_alias`.* FROM `machinemanager_machine_meter` AS `main_table` INNER JOIN `machinemanager_machine_metertype` AS `table_alias` ON machinemanager_machine_metertype.meter_type_id = machinemanager_machine_meter.meter_type

Here is my simple request.  My model resources to join:

```
Mage::getModel('machinemanager/machine_meter') //main table 'meter_id' is foreign key
Mage::getModel('machinemanager/machine_metertype') //table to join
```

So I can understand as a simple example, I'd like to end up with `$collection` as all fields of both machine_meter and machine_meter_type tables.

Could you please show me how to end up with a correct use of `$collection->getSelect()->join(...`?  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$collection->getSelect()->join(
   array(/* joined table alias = */ 'machine_metertype' => $collection->getTable('machinemanager/machine_metertype')),
   'main_table.meter_id = machine_metertype.meter_type_id',
    /* array of columns */ array()
);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you.  How do I '->getData()' of all the fields across the joined table?  'var_dump($collection->getData())' results in only the fields of machine_meter and not the meter types.  Thanks for your efforts to help me.

Comment: you have to specify the columns you want from joined table in the array of columns that I left empty in the example; if you want all the columns, use  'array('*')`

Comment: Great.  I found too I am able to assign field names to the joined fields this way, e.g. `array('newfieldname' => 'sort_order')`.  Thanks.